# LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ, openCV, qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Вообщем произошла ошибка LNK2019, можете помочь выявить ее.

MainWinow CPP
https://pastebin.com/VJKW518s

MainWinow H
https://pastebin.com/1mm3V65M

Ошибка

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,class cv::CascadeClassifier &,class cv::CascadeClassifier &,class cv::CascadeClassifier &,double)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAVCascadeClassifier@3@11N@Z) в функции "public: void __cdecl MainWindow::proccesFrameUpdGui(void)" (?proccesFrameUpdGui@MainWindow@@QEAAXXZ)
```

Comment: Можем помочь, можем не помочь... Ищите, почему у вас функция объявлена, но реализована.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил я забыл перед описанием методом поставить, принадлежность метода класса. `MainWindow::`
Всем спасибо.